# How to read an Excel file all at once in servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I know just the basics about jxl or apache poi. I have a code which retrieves the data row-wise and hence takes a lot of time. Is there a way that i can read the whole excel file at once and create a table of the data retrieved and then put it into my database with some data duplicacy checks? I hope I'm clear. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You have what code? What evidence do you have that row-wise takes a lot of time? How much time? Where is the file coming from? If it's on your local disk, can you convert it to CSV?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Comment: @JozefChocholacek noted, Thanks!

Comment: Noted but not acted on in any way.

Comment: @user207421  well now i acted on your kind advice and hence asked another question regarding this. Kindly try to answer it. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641127/time-efficient-program-for-importing-an-excel-sheet-and-then-storing-it-into-db)

Answer (score 1):

Fillo is a good option for your case. 
You can use select query to fetch all records at once.
You may refer to the link below:
https://codoid.com/fillo/

Hope it helps.